# weighted graph - find all paths from X to y with max stops

Tags: java, graph, graph-theory, dijkstra

I'm working on a Java project that needs to, between other things, return all possible paths from x to y with a max stops.

E.g. Every node is a city, and  every path from one city to another has a cost values.

I'm using this article by reference, and here is the same models I'm using. 
http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaAlgorithmsDijkstra/article.html

It works fine to return the shortest path from x to Y , but I need ALL the possible paths and costs of each.

For example:

Find all available routes from any given pair of towns within a given maximum number of stops.

Input graph:
AB5, BC4, CD8, DC8, DE6, AD5, CE2, EB3, AE7

Routes from C and ending at C with a maximum of 3 stops:

CDC  (2 stops)
CEBC (3 stops)

Routes from A and ending at C with a maximum of 4 stops:

ABC   (2 stops)
ADC   (2 stops)
AEBC  (3 stops)
ADEBC (4 stops)

Comment: I think you actually meant to say "all possible paths with each node visited once max"? Because otherwise the number of possible paths is infinite.

Comment: I've updated  the question for better understanding.

Comment: For more efficient help post [mcve] with test data and expected output.

Answer (score 0):

The weight of each one of your node links is the distance between the two.

i.e) A---> 7 ----> B ---> 3 ---> C ---> etc...

In this instance, the total weight of this path from A to C would be the sum of all weights (distances) between each co-ordinate.

All of the possible paths below a maximum can be recorded with the above calculation described

Comment: Didn't understand. I've updated the question for better understanding.

Comment: You need the distance between the two points in your graph. 

A--(distanceFromAtoB)--B--(distanceFromBtoC)--C (2 stops)

Answer (score 0):

I'd use BFS instead of Dijkstra to be honest. You're not looking for shortest path, but any path. So you can just run BFS from a node x and after it does k steps (I'll call your max steps as k) you can stop it. Every time it reaches y, you can add the path to your answer.